# adding a colorbar to a scatterplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to add a colorbar to a scatterplot. Currently a discrete legend is generated that needs to be modified to colorbar. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance,

```
library(ggplot2)    
x_axis<-sample(1:55)
y_axis<-sample(100:154)

plotName<-'Scatter plot with colorbar instead of discrete legend'
color_plate <- colorRampPalette(colors = c('dodgerblue4','dodgerblue','green3','green2','yellow2','red','darkred'),space='Lab') #v1
color_plate <- color_plate(55) 


  dat_1 <- data.frame(xvar = x_axis, 
             yvar = y_axis,

col1 <- c(rep(1,8),rep(2,8),rep(3,8),rep(4,8),rep(5,8),rep(6,8),rep(7,7)))              
# col1<-(rep(1,6),rep(2,6),rep(3,6),rep(4,6),rep(5,6),rep(6,6),rep(7,6),rep(8,6),rep(9,7))) 
chart<-ggplot(dat_1, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) +
         geom_point(shape=19,size=5,aes(colour = col1)) +

 scale_colour_continuous( low = "blue", high = "red", space ="Lab",name="observation",label=rep("",7) , #nrow(dat_1)
 guide = guide_legend(direction = "horizontal", title.position = "bottom",     title.hjust=0.5) ) +

         theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
         labs(title=plotName)+
         scale_y_continuous(expression(atop('Net'~CO[2]~'Flux '~CO[2]~' (β)' )))+   
         scale_x_continuous(expression(atop('Gross'~CO[2]))) 

print(chart)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be easier if we knew why you chose those particular colors. If they are essentially arbitrary, then perhaps this would work:

```
### add a column for color
dat_1 <- data.frame(xvar = x_axis, 
                  yvar = y_axis,
                  col1 = 1:7)
```

**edit** This should be close to what you want

```
ggplot(dat_1, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) +
 geom_point(shape=19, size=5, aes(colour = col1)) +
 scale_colour_continuous( low = "blue", high = "red", space = "Lab",
  name="observation", label=rep("", nrow(dat_1)) ,
  guide = guide_legend(direction = "horizontal", 
   title.position = "bottom",     title.hjust=0.5) ) +
 theme(legend.position = "bottom")  +
 scale_y_continuous(expression(atop('Net'~CO[2]~'Flux '~CO[2]~' (β)' ))) +   
 scale_x_continuous(expression(atop('Gross'~CO[2])))
```

Which gives

[image]

Following your comments, I have made the labels 'blank' by passing `""` as the value. Changing appearance follows the help for [guide legend](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guide_legend.html). 
If you have 55 observations and want all of them to have one of 7 color values, then:

```
dat_1$col1 <- rep(seq(7), 8)[-7*8]
```

should do it for you. You can change the colors to suit your tastes. I like [`scale_color_brewer`](http://www.personal.psu.edu/cab38/ColorBrewer/ColorBrewer.html)  personally as it's easy to see which are suitable for a colorblind audience.

**update2**

I think there may be a typo in your code. 
The following works for me:

```
set.seed(1)
dat_1 <- data.frame(xvar = sample(1:55),
                    yvar = sample(100:154),
                    col1 = c(seq(10), rep(seq(15), each=3))
                    )
```

Then plot as above and you'll have 55 points with a color scale of 15 hues.

Comment: I think you have a great answer there +1

Comment: Hi, this looks great. Just couple of minor changes: 1) Can we get rid of count 1:7 in the barplot display and 2) can the title 'observation' come below the colorbar? thanks for the help.

Comment: Regarding why i chose these colors: I wanted distinct colors including red,green,blue,yellow,orange to assign each point a distinct color on the chart. In original plot I have 55 points and I intend to spread these 7 colors(shades) into 55 distinct values. Please suggest if this information helps in making a colorbar with original colors in the query.

Comment: hi, this is better but am still stuck on dat_1$col1. I tried to give separate value to each point in the bigger data frame but that is not working. I am still working on it and may ask some more help on this in a day or two but thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm... I guess you've tried `dat_1$col1 <- seq(55)`? Perhaps you could could give us a representative example? Consider using `sample()` to generate a similar set rather than posting the raw data...

Comment: hi, i hv modified the code to generate 55 random points. Its is doing fine for 7 groups of colors but not working if i try to generate 9 or more colors. Also observe the modification i made in label of color scale to have same subgroup elements together in allocation of colors.

Comment: hi, your suggestions are of great help and based on our requirement and your help I have modified the code. Just need to balance the colourbar between blue and red for which I have posted a fresh question, please look at the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017836/distribution-of-colours-in-a-colourbar-using-ggplot

Comment: hi, is it possible to increase the length width of grid box in the plot. May be by moving the colourbar further down or otherwise?

Comment: Don't understand. Do you want the grid squares (white lines in background) to be larger, i.e. fewer squares? Or want to make the whole plot wider i.e. change aspect ratio?